# Reading from CSV and merging content in rows into an array

Tags: php, csv

pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/4YCdbrsP

Input CSV format,

```
number | itemid
1001, 121212
1001, 12991
1042, 99878
1042, 89776
1042, 87777
1045, 11010
1046, 22299
1049, 9875
```

Expected Output

```
[1001 => {121212,12991}]
[1042 => {99878, 89776, 87777}]
[1045 => {11010}]
[1046 => {22299}]
[1049 => {9875}]
```

I am trying to read each line from a CSV file which has contents as specified above (two columns, each row containing "number" as the first column and an associated "itemid" as the second column.

If the next line has the same "number" then, I would like its corresponding "itemid" to be pushed to an array. Repeat this, if the next line(s) have the same "number".

Following is where I have gotten so far.

```
  $row = 0;

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE && $row < 8) {
        $sku = $data[0];
        $upc = $data[1];
        $skuUpcList = array($sku => array());
        array_push($skuUpcList[$sku], $upc);

        $row++;

        while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE && $row < 8) {
            if($data[0] == $sku) {
                array_push($skuUpcList[$sku], $data[1]);
                $row++;
            } else {
                $sku = $data[0];
                $upc = $data[1];
                $skuUpcList = array($sku => array());
                array_push($skuUpcList[$sku], $data[1]);
                $row++; 
            }
            $skuUpcList = array_unique($skuUpcList);
            var_dump($skuUpcList); 
            echo  '<br>';
        }


    }
```

=== Output of the above script ===

```
array(1) { [1001]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "121212" [1]=> string(5) "12991" } } 
array(1) { [1042]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "99878" } } 
array(1) { [1042]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "99878" [1]=> string(5) "89776" } } 
array(1) { [1042]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "99878" [1]=> string(5) "89776" [2]=> string(5) "87777" } } 
array(1) { [1045]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "11010" } } 
array(1) { [1046]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "22299" } } 
array(1) { [1049]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "9875" } }
```

As you can see, even though the script runs fine, I am trying to make sure that the script echos each "number" only once but, as per the above output the "number" 1042 appears three times.

I have tried to move the var_dump() statement outside the 2nd while loop but, it doesn't seem to help.

Any help regarding this would be helpful.

pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/4YCdbrsP

Comment: If the csv file is not too big, you may consider a different and better approach.

Comment: csv has at least 300,000 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work quite nicely:

```
<?php

$handle = fopen("xxx.csv", "r");

$row = 0;
$skuUpcList = array();

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE && $row < 8) {
    $sku = $data[0];
    $upc = $data[1];

    if ( array_key_exists($sku, $skuUpcList) ) {
        $skuUpcList[$sku][] = $upc;
    } else {
        $skuUpcList[$sku] = array($upc);
    }
    $row++;
}

print_r( $skuUpcList );
```

Comment: even though the input csv has over 300,000 rows, I think I will move forward with this approach.

Comment: @SrikanthAD If you are going to create an array with 300,000 occurances you will likely blow PHP's memory limit. You may need to add this to the top of this script `ini_set('memory_limit','256M');` where the size is something you will need to play with until you get it right. Its better to do this rather than modify the php.ini file as that will effect every script and this only effects this one script.

Answer (score 3):

```
$skuUpcList = array();

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $skuUpcList[$data[0]] []= $data[1];
}
```

Comment: Even though he picked my answer, presumably becasue it was a bit easier for a beginner to understand I personnally think your answer is better and more elegant. So I have upvoted yours.